# PHP exit and still output buffer

Tags: php, output-buffering

Is it possible to exit the script, say on a fatal error and still output my buffer? I am using a template system that executes the header/content/footer. So I am trying to make it so it'll stop code executing on the `fatal_error()` function but still output the buffer template (which sends out the error message to the user while still maintaining the website template.) I use `ob_start("ob_gzhandler")` and in my `fatal_error()` function I use `ob_flush()` and I end up with a white screen when `fatal_error()` is called. Here's my function

```
function fatal_error($error_message, $log = true)
{
    setup_error($error_message);

    ob_flush();
    exit();
}
```

`setup_error()` tells the script to change the content body to the error message (so it doesn't parse 1/2 the body when the error occurs). All the examples I've looked through says `ob_flush()` or `ob_end_flush()` can achieve this, though I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `set_error_handler()` function.  This way you can assign a user-defined function, in your case `fatal_error()`, to execute when PHP encounters an error.  You can do whatever you like in your function, including flushing the buffer and exiting.

**EDIT:**

The following code should do what you want:

```
set_error_handler('fatal_error', E_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR);

function fatal_error($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    ob_flush();
    exit();
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

You can trigger an E_ERROR and therefore test the `fatal_error()` function like so:

```
trigger_error('This is a test error', E_ERROR);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try also adding a call to `flush()` before the `ob_flush()`. Sometimes, both are needed.

Comment: hmm, still only outputting a white screen

Comment: Oops, the template wasn't outputting until after `ob_flush`. I looked that over.